# Unsupported languages in Postgres Full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

My web application supports 3 languages, English, Traditional Chinese, Vietnamese. I understand that Traditional Chinese and Vietnamese is not supported in Postgres' Full Text Search.

If I were to go ahead and implement Full Text Search, what will happen if a text search is performed using an unsupported language?

Answer (score 1):

There are Postgres extensions to handle Chinese. Have you tried http://pgxn.org/dist/zhparser/? You can then maybe port it to Vietnamese.

Comment: It would be better if you also answered the question. (*"What will happen if ...?)"*